# How to avoid code smell(else..if) syntax?

Tags: python, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Below is the Jenkins groovy script to push the artifacts to Cloud foundry.

```
    stage('stage_1'){

        if (repoName == 'a'){

            pushA(repoName)    
        }
        else if(repoName == 'b'){

            pushB(repoName)  
        }
        else if (repoName == 'c'){

            pushC(repoName)
        }else if (repoName == 'd'){

            pushD(repoName)                
        }else if (repoName == 'e'){

            pushE(repoName)
        }
    }
```

---

This is a single file Jenkins groovy script, written using below option, webhooked with multiple GitLab repositories:

### [image]

Why pushA/pushB? because every push has its own manifest file

How to avoid `else..if` code smell?

Do you suggest hashmap with `repoName` as key?

if yes, how to register a `pushX()` method during start of script? In python we use registration decorator(run at import time) to update `commands` dictionary, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Really not clear why do you need any 'if'...  When you just need push(repoName)...

Comment: @daggett Because every push has its own `manifest.yml` file that pipeline overwrites, based on Dev/QA/Prod space in PCF

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that approximately corresponds to your python. However that's just putting key-closure into a map...

```
def registry=[:]
def register(String key, Closure c){ registry[key]=c }

register('f1'){ println 'running f1' }

registry.f1() // this will call f1
```

Comment: The answer remains the same. Your problem is not clear. I don't see any reason you can't use the map.

Comment: I have `pushA()` as method outside `node(){}`  scope with syntax `def pushA(){...}`

Answer (score 0):

The code below defines dummy `pushX()` functions to mimic the ones in your example, then define a map of closures where each closure calls the relevant `pushX()` function, then looks up the relevant closure by name and invokes it, passing the name as a parameter:

```
def pushA(def name) { println "In pushA() with $name" }
def pushB(def name) { println "In pushB() with $name" }

def funcMap = [
    a: { pushA(it) },
    b: { pushB(it) }
]

def repoName = 'a'

// Invoke the closure mapped to 'repoName', also passing 'repoName' as a parameter.
funcMap[repoName].call(repoName)
```

Maybe something like that would work for you. This still smells pretty bad though; if `pushA()` is only ever used when pushing to repo A, why does it need the repo name as a parameter? There may well be a better way to organise this whole thing, including the parts not shown above.

Answer (score 0):

you can emulate a switch with a dispached dict. Bellow a silly example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def case1():
    print("This is case 1")

def case2():
    print("This is case 2")

def case3():
    print("This is case 3")


token_dict = {
    "case1" : case1,
    "case2" : case2,
    "case3" : case3,
}


def main():
    cases = ("case1", "case3", "case2", "case1")
    for case in cases:
        token_dict[case]()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
This is case 1
This is case 3
This is case 2
This is case 1
```